# Cannot connecting heroku postgresql database to localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, postgresql, heroku

I am trying to work on a web app developed by someone else on Heroku. After pulling the source code, I installed PostgreSQL 9.3 on my computer.

Tried to import the existing database on Heroku but it did not seem to work:

```
$ export HEROKU_POSTGRES_IVORY_URL=postgres:///$(user)
```

Tried using the following settings in my database.yml file:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: app-dev
  host: localhost
  username: user
  password: (password created when installing PostgreSQL)
```

But this produced the following error when I try to run the app locally:

```
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/act
ive_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1222:in `initialize': FATAL
:  password authentication failed for user "user" (PG::ConnectionBad)
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3
.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1222:in `new'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3
.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1222:in `conne
ct'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3
.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:324:in `initia
lize'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3
.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `new'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3
.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `postgre
sql_connection'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3
.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:315:in `
new_connection'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3
.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:325:in `
checkout_new_connection'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3
.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:247:in `
block (2 levels) in checkout'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3
.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `
loop'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3
.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `
block in checkout'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_s
ynchronize'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3
.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:239:in `
checkout'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3
.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:102:in `
block in connection'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_s
ynchronize'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3
.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:101:in `
connection'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3
.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:410:in `
retrieve_connection'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3
.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb
:171:in `retrieve_connection'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3
.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb
:145:in `connection'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3
.2.18/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:310:in `clear_cache!'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3
.2.18/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:103:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-
3.2.18/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:418:in `_run__445699908__prepare__2175577
33__callbacks'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-
3.2.18/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-
3.2.18/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_prepare_callbacks'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-
3.2.18/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2
.18/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:74:in `prepare!'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2
.18/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:48:in `prepare!'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.1
8/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:47:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.1
8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.1
8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.1
8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.1
8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.1
8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.1
8/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.1
8/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
        from c:/Users/Alison/young-lake-3173/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (r
equired)>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-
3.2.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-
3.2.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-
3.2.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-
3.2.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
        from c:/Users/Alison/young-lake-3173/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib
/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib
/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
        from c:/Users/Alison/young-lake-3173/config.ru:in `new'
        from c:/Users/Alison/young-lake-3173/config.ru:in `<main>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib
/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib
/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib
/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.1
8/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib
/rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib
/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.1
8/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.1
8/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.1
8/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.1
8/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I've been over the instructions on Heroku over and over and cannot seem to find a solution. I am relatively new to this so some pointers would be much appreciated!

I am developing an app with Ruby on Rails and I am using Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend checking the pg_hba.conf file first, which for windows should be located at:

`C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\data\pg_hba.conf`

On the bottom of the file you should see something along the lines of:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
```

Does your conf file differ greatly from what is above?

- If you do make any changes to this file remember to restart postgres